# How to Log Metrics (eg. Validation Loss) To TensorBoard when using Pytorch Lightning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I am using Pytorch Lightning to train my models (on GPU devices, using DDP) and TensorBoard is the default logger used by Lightning.

My code is setup to log the training and validation loss on each training and validation step respectively.

```py
class MyLightningModel(pl.LightningModule):

    def training_step(self, batch):
        x, labels = batch
        out = self(x)
        loss = F.mse_loss(out, labels)
        self.log("train_loss", loss)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch):
        x, labels = batch
        out = self(x)
        loss = F.mse_loss(out, labels)
        self.log("val_loss", loss)
        return loss
```

TensorBoard correctly plots both the `train_loss` and `val_loss` charts in the `SCALERS` tab. However, in the `HPARAMS` tab, on the left side bar, only `hp_metric` is visible under `Metrics`.

[image]

However, in the `HPARAMS` tab, on the left side bar, only `hp_metric` is visible under `Metrics`.

[image]

How can we add `train_loss` and `val_loss` to the `Metrics` section? This way, we will be able to use `val_loss` in the `PARALLEL COORDINATES VIEW` instead of `hp_metric`.

**Image showing `hp_metric` and no `val_loss`:**
[image]

*Using Pytorch 1.8.1, Pytorch Lightning 1.2.6, TensorBoard 2.4.1*

Answer (score 2):

- You can use `self.logger.log_hyperparams` method to log hyperparameters and metrics in tensorboard. (see [pytorch lightning tensorboard docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.loggers.tensorboard.html#pytorch_lightning.loggers.tensorboard.TensorBoardLogger.log_hyperparams))
- The values you added by `self.log` will be displayed in hparam plugin if and only if you have passed same key names in `metric`. (see [pytorch tensorboard docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_hparams))

Sample code ([full code](https://github.com/hankyul2/PytorchLightningSnippet/blob/main/pl_hyperparameter.ipynb)):

```py
class BasicModule(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, lr=0.01):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = models.resnet18(pretrained=False)
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        self.lr = lr
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        
        metric = MetricCollection({'top@1': Accuracy(top_k=1), 'top@5': Accuracy(top_k=5)})
        self.train_metric = metric.clone(prefix='train/')
        self.valid_metric = metric.clone(prefix='valid/')
    
    def on_train_start(self) -> None:
        # log hyperparams
        self.logger.log_hyperparams(self.hparams, {'train/top@1': 0, 'train/top@5': 0, 'valid/top@1': 0, 'valid/top@5': 0})
        return super().on_train_start()
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx, optimizer_idx=None):
        return self.shared_step(*batch, self.train_metric)

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        return self.shared_step(*batch, self.valid_metric)

    def shared_step(self, x, y, metric):
        y_hat = self.model(x)
        loss = self.criterion(y_hat, y)
        self.log_dict(metric(y_hat, y), prog_bar=True)
        return loss

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # default_hp_metric=False
    logger = loggers.TensorBoardLogger('', 'lightning_logs', default_hp_metric=False)
    trainer = Trainer(max_epochs=2, gpus='0,', logger=logger, precision=16)
```